# Proxyquire and functions import

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I m trying to use proxyquire to simulate an express behaviour and I m having some trouble dealing with the following command :

```
expressProxy = () => {
      return {
        use: () => true,
        post: () => true,
        listen: () => true
      }
    }

Application = proxyquire('./../app', {
      'express': expressProxy,
      'passport': passportProxy,
      './app/business/service/StrategyFactory': StrategyFactoryProxy
    })
```

When I start my application using the following code :

```
Application.main()
```

I m always having the full express behaviour, as it should normally work.

I m having the full and complete express object just as if it hasn't been redefined...

I m a bit lost and I dont understand what's going on here.

Any information to help me understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default proxyquire passes all method calls through to the original dependency.
You can turn it off using '@noCallThru' if you want to disable it for specific stubs:

```
var foo = proxyquire('./foo', {
  path: {
      extname: function (file) { ... }
    , '@noCallThru': true
  }
});
```

or `.noCallThru()` if you want to turn it off for all stubs:

```
// all stubs resolved by proxyquireStrict will not call through by default
var proxyquireStrict = require('proxyquire').noCallThru();
```

See https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire#preventing-call-thru-to-original-dependency for a full explanation